# Test onNotification Click using minSdk 15

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to test clicking on notification behavior AND there is `UIAUTOMATOR` framework for this purpose.

But my minSDK is `15` and `UIAUTOMATOR` framework minSDK is `18`

Is there any alternative solution outhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the meantime I ignored that issue by override the library inside my **Manifest.xml (androidTest)** :

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android_libs.ub_uiautomator"/>
```